# Are product attribute names accessible from Magento API?

Tags: api, product-attribute, rest-api, enterprise-1.14

My goal is to pull this information as a guest but I have tried as both an admin and a guest. My results look like this:

URL: {magento_base_url}/m/api/rest/products/category/12

```
 <magento_api>
  <entity_id>10011</entity_id>
    <type_id>grouped</type_id>
    <sku>ITEM-SKU</sku>
    <attribute_code>attributeid</attribute_code>
    <attribute_code>attributeid</attribute_code>
    <attribute_code>attributeid</attribute_code>
    <attribute_code>attributeid</attribute_code>
    <attribute_code>attributeid</attribute_code>
...
</magento_api>
```

Of course, attribute_code is the actual product attribute code like  and attribute_id is a numerical value.

**Edit for Clarification**

In my example `<attribute_code>attributeid</attribute_code>` represents `<description>80</description>` or 2`.

What I am hoping for is let's say my `attribute_code = "multiple_select_for_product_features"` and `attributeid=20 and label="Product Features"` and selected `value="Resistent to water"`. How would I pull the label and value?

Comment: You are need <attribute_code>attributeid</attribute_code> to 
<description>80</description>

right?

Comment: No, In my example `<attribute_code>attributeid</attribute_code>` represents `<description>80</description>` or <color>2</color>`. 

What I am hoping for is let's say my attribute_code = "multiple_select_for_product_features" and attributeid=20 and label="Product Features" and selected value="Resistent to water". How would I pull the label and value?

Comment: Do you own Magento instance codebase to extend API?

Comment: I am able to extend the Magento codebase but have little working knowledge of Magento's API.